# To get data for the last 5 days when date is stored as int in julian format

Tags: t-sql, date-conversion, julian-date, jdedwards

I'm new to sql and need help on a query.

Database is JDEdwards
In my database i have a column 'jdt' with Julian date stored as integer.
Now i have to write a query to extract last 5 days data from the present day.
My thinking approach is to convert current current date to Julian date as int and then juliandate-5

For example: Julian date=117209 i.e 2017-07-28
last 5 days date i.e 2017-07-23 -> 117204

I also have to do this in single query, i cannot add columns to existing table. And also this query needs t be generalized for every date i.e if i run this query it should automatically take that date of run.

Is my approach correct if yes, Please help me on the query.
If there is a better approach please advise on this

TIA

Answer (score 1):

"Julian" dates are the number of days since a specific date.

JDE uses a compressed date format you would have to convert to an actual date, so you cannot do integer math on a JDE date:
All versions of JDE use a Julian Date format as follows: CYYDDD where C = Century; YY = a 2 digit year; and DD = the 3 digit number representing the day of the year

To convert the JDE date to an actual date:

```
Declare @jdedate int;
SET @jdedate = 117209

SELECT DATEADD(DAY,(@jdedate%1000)-1, DATEADD(YEAR,(@jdedate/1000),'1900-01-01'))
```

To convert current date to JDE date:

```
SELECT (DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())-1900) * 1000 + DATEPART(dayofyear,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Getting the error while using getdate() in JDEdwards   Error: [SQL0204] GETDATE in *LIBL type *N not found.
SQLState:  42704
ErrorCode: -204

Comment: Thanku Tom for the conversion query.   But may i know how can i select data from table for last 5 days based on a column which is julian date

Comment: i have to write this query on JDEdwards system. Following query worked            
select 
CAST(CASE
            WHEN SUBSTRING(TO_CHAR(current_timestamp, 'yyyy'), 1, 1) = '2'
                THEN '1'
            ELSE '0'
            END || TO_CHAR(current_timestamp, 'yyddd') AS INT).

Comment: But how can i retrieve only the data from past 5 days and this job occurs for every 3 days.                                                                                                          The query should be written on JDE systems and seems like most date parameter doesn't seem to work. Please advise on this as there is a deadline coming up for me to submit this                                                                         TIA

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question sitting out there, and thought I might add some information.  I use Oracle for our JDE system, and I have always converted the dates in the following manner:

```
 TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(WMTRDJ+1900000),'YYYYDDD') AS "Date - Order/Transaction Date",
```

The column in this case is WMTRDJ and will convert the Julian date to the standard Gregorian date.

Once converted in the SELECT you can use a standard date comparison in your query.  Like this (based on your default NLS_DATE_FORMAT):

```
 WHERE TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(WMTRDJ+1900000),'YYYYDDD') BETWEEN '5-JAN-2012' AND '6-JAN-2012'
```

I hope this helps!